# Is there any difference between spark-shell and scala CLI client?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

spark-shell and scala CLI client offer similar functionality; is there any difference between both of them ?

Answer (score 4):

Spark-shell reuses the latest Scala REPL to reduce code maintenance; the REPL made some changes to how snippets are wrapped to accommodate Spark. (Cf `-Yrepl-class-based`.)

However, some bugs remain, especially related to how import history is used when wrapping or templating.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9799

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9881

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10045

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be fair to say that the Spark REPL is a functional superset of the Scala REPL. Just about anything you can do in the Scala REPL can be done in the Spark REPL (of course the Scala REPL cannot do everything that the Spark REPL can do).

However, implementation-wise the two are quite different. Spark needs to be able to run on a distributed set of drivers so it operates very differenly from the Scala REPL ([this post](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Why-does-spark-REPL-not-embed-scala-REPL-td6871.html) expands on some of the technical differences).

Answer (score 0):

Spark-shell is a command line interface to analyze data in Spark cluster interactively which supports Scala. Similar to spark-shell, Spark has pyspark shell for Python. It provides a special object Sparkcontext(sc) to interact with Spark cluster.

Scala cli is an interactive command line interface to try Scala commands. It is used to quickly check the Scala commands/api.

If you want to analyze Spark data using Scala go for Spark shell and if you want to try some Scala commands for for Spark cli